# Finding the Sum of Sides on the Bases of Parallelograms in a Series

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I'm currently engrossed in solving a captivating mathematical problem presented in the context of the Bangladesh Math Olympiad ($2017$). This particular problem delves into the fascinating world of parallelograms and presents an intriguing construction challenge.

**Problem Description:**

> $AEJF$ is a parallelogram, whose base $FJ$ has
> length $1$. $B, I$ is taken such that the area of
> $ABF, BFIE, IJE$ are equal. Again, $C, G$ are
> taken from parallelogram $BFIE$ in a similar
> way. If, we continue like this, what is the
> summation of the sides which are on the base
> of each parallelogram?

[image: AEJF parallelogram]

As I draw this mathematical journey to a close, the enigma of constructing parallelograms with equi-area triangles still looms large. Despite diligent efforts, I find myself at a mathematical crossroads, unable to discern a clear pattern or solution to this captivating problem. If you can offer any fresh perspectives, additional insights, or a comprehensive solution to decipher the mysteries of this intriguing problem, I would be immensely grateful.

Your expertise and support are invaluable in my quest to unravel the intricacies of this mathematical puzzle. I look forward to your contributions and extend my heartfelt thanks in advance for your assistance in solving this captivating parallelogram construction mystery.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself, such as calculating the length of $FI$?

Comment: If the two triangles and inner parallelogram are all the same area, then that area has to be $\frac 13$ the area of the outer parallelogram. What does that tell you about the bases of the outer triangles vs the base of the inner triangle?